# Strange zen movie - what happens here?

Tags: zen

Can someone precisely explain me what is actually happen (and why) on this movie - ?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_A-9pxBANek

[image]

Comment: Comments say that this is a shortened version of the video, which has been reposted many times on the internet, and that a longer version elsewhere shows his waking up again some minutes later -- and that he intended it as a demonstration.

Comment: It's not Zen by the way -- according to comments it's Theravada and the script on the coffin shows it's in Myanmar.

Answer (score 0):

He consciously chose his death. It is possible for someone with great spiritual power to leave his body at will.

Comment: you don't need miraculous spiritual powers to commit suicide. It looks like these are known practices - why do they do it?

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski It is not suicide. It is leaving body at will. Generally in suicide lots of anxiety is involved. But here there is peaceful exit from the body.